# How to assign formGroup to an array for form validation

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a repeater section in angular, i followed the below method to achive it, but i want to validate the form (Enable or disable the final submit button based on the validation),Here is the sample code.

ts file:-

```
      private formBuilder : FormBuilder
) { }
 
formInfoHolder = [];

onAdd(){
    let newForm = {
         let newForm = {
    subText : new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(250)]),
    header : new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(20)]),
    link : new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z]*')]),  
}
        
    }
    this.formInfoHolder.push(this.formBuilder.group(newForm))
}
delete(toDelete){
    let del : any[] = [];
    for(let form of this.formInfoHolder){
       if(toDelete !== form){
            del.push(form);
       }
    }
    this.formInfoHolder = del;
}
```

then in HTML Component

```
<div *ngFor="let form of formInfoHolder">
     <form [formGroup]="form">
         <label for="username"> Username </label>
         <input id="username" type="text" formControlName="username">
         <!-- insert other input elements with the formControlName -->
         <label for="delete"> Delete </label>
         <input id="delete" type="button" (click)="delete(form)">
     </form>
</div>
<button (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>
<button [disabled]="//Here i want to validate" (click)="saveInfo()">Save</button>
```

How do i validate the form(enable the button only if all the fields are filled) which is stored in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xbjhh5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for what you are looking for
I have used formarray and added formgroups into it, adding and removing formgroups becomes easy in formarray. Also validation also becomes easy because I only have check if the main form in valid

Comment: So this is another aproach for repeative form..Worked Thanks a lot!

Comment: if it at the time of form creation that you want to set conditional validator then you can do it using ternary operator. eg: `subText: new FormControl('', [ somecondition ? Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(250) : null])`

Comment: if you want to set dynamically after form creation then you have to do it inside some function and add validators using setValidator() and remove them using clearValidators(). Also remeber to update the form using updateValueAndValidity. eg: `this.form.updateValueAndValidity()`

Comment: @SaiGowtham can you make changes to stackblitz example with this error. I will check and make necessary changes as per your requirement

Comment: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pp7jqi?file=src/app/app.component.html) Here the save button is disabled even if i fill the required details for the banner,I ahve 2 formGroups to enable/disable the button,In this case i need to make the fields reuqired based on the drop don selection, can you please help me through this,,

Comment: hey @SaiGowtham [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yabzpp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) of the update. I have removed disable from the form but I have added validation on submission of the form. I hope this should work for you.

Comment: Thank you soo much Shailesh, This helped a lot

Comment: Hi @Shailesh, I have a doubt regarding angular upgrade,So i upgraded the angular from v10 to 11, in Angular 11 on page load itself the validators are kicking in for all the reactive form fields, Can you please help in this?

Comment: Hey @kusuru I have not really worked on angular 11 but I don't think there should be any major difference in them for reactive forms. Don't really know what the issue can be without looking at code

Comment: Okay no worries..

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you can use `.invalid` on the `formGroup` you created, so it will be like this:

```
<button [disabled]="newForm.invalid" (click)="saveInfo()">Save</button>
```